# Basic inequality in a Banach Algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, banach-algebras

Suppose $x$ is an element of a Banach Algebra. Let $U$ be an open set in $\mathbb{C}$ containing the spectrum of $x$. Is it true, that inf $\{\|(x-\lambda1_A)^{-1}\|^{-1}:\lambda \in \mathbb{C}-U \}>0?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's true.  In particular, note that $V = \Bbb C - U$ is a *closed* subset of $\Bbb C$.  As such, the continuous function
$$
f:V \to [0,\infty)\\
\lambda \mapsto \|(x - \lambda 1)^{-1}\|^{-1}
$$
Satisfies $\lim_{|\lambda| \to \infty} \|(x - \lambda 1)^{-1}\|^{-1} = \infty$.  As such, there exists an $R > 0$ such that $|\lambda| > R \implies f(\lambda) > 1$. By continuity, $f$ must attain a minimum over the compact set $\{\lambda \in V : |\lambda| \leq R\}$. However, since we cannot have $f(\lambda) = 0$, this minimum cannot be zero.

---

For that limit: note that
$$
\lim_{|\lambda| \to \infty} \|(x - \lambda 1)^{-1}\|^{-1}  = 
\lim_{|\lambda| \to \infty} |\lambda| \cdot \|(\frac 1{\lambda}x -  1)^{-1}\|^{-1}
$$
but $\|(\frac 1{\lambda}x -  1)^{-1}\| \to \|1\| = 1$.

Comment: Nice argument. But is it clear, that $lim_{|\lambda| \to \infty} \|(x - \lambda 1)^{-1}\|^{-1} = \infty$?

Comment: Yes; see my latest edit.